# Why is len(file.read()) giving me a value of zero?

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, eof, seek

Why are the values of print len() different for both functions? Are they not the same?

The file this script is opening was a text file with three lines of text. i named it test.txt and inside it was

```
Jack and Jill
gave up 
they went home with no water
```

Code:

```
def function2nd (filename):
        target = open(theFile, 'r')
        inData = target.read()
        print inData
        print len(inData)
        target.close()
theFile = raw_input("What is the file name?\n>>")
function2nd(theFile)

def function3rd (filename):
        target = open(theFile, 'r')
        target.read()
        print target.read()
        print len(target.read())
        target.close()

function3rd(theFile)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Files act like a long tape in a casette; you can read the file but by the time you are done you have passed the tape all the way to the end. Reading again won't give you the data *again*.

As such your second function tried to read data from a file that is already wound all the way to the end.

You can rewind the 'tape' by re-opening the file, or by using `target.seek(0)` to send it back to the start.

Comment: so does that mean, regardless whether i put target.read() into a variable it can only be read through once?

Comment: @AsaphKim: Files have a *read and write position*. When you call `file.read()` all data in the file is returned and the file position is left all the way at the end. Calling `file.read()` then again means it cannot go any further so it'll return an empty string. By re-opening the file you start the file position at the start again, or you can use `file.seek()` to move the file position manually.

Comment: Why dont i have to call file.seek() when i put file.read() into a variable?

Comment: @Asaph: why should you? You just opened the file, so the file position is at the start still.

Comment: does that mean i have multiple instances of the file open, whenever i run multiple iterations of function(inData)?

Comment: Each time you run one of the two functions you open a new instance of the file.

Comment: Having multiple instances of the file open for read is overkill in this case. If all you want to do is measure its length, store its `len(...)` into a variable, then do `seek()`

Answer (score 1):

Well, the second one you read the open file then call `len`, but the file object is empty at that point.

In the first one you read the file, put the contents into a variable, then take the length of the variable.