# Bulk Mailing multiple Attachments result in corrupted files in Flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I am writing a FlaskMail application with attachments which is a WTForm's`MultipleFileField`. I am also reading the emails from a xlsx file and sending the emails in bulk with multiple attachments.
However only the first person in the list is able to read the attachments and the rest get a corrupted version of the files.

Here is my Code :

### Code

```
    with mail.connect() as conn:
        for contact in contacts:
            message = "Hi %s \n\n" % (contact['name']).capitalize()
            message += body
            subject = subject
            msg = Message(recipients=(contact['email']).split(),
                          sender=sender,
                          html=message,
                          subject=subject,
                          )
            for f in request.files.getlist('attachment'):
                msg.attach(filename=f.filename,
                           content_type=f.content_type,
                           data=f.read())
            conn.send(msg)
        return Response("Success")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28654319/why-is-lenfile-read-giving-me-a-value-of-zero) post.

```
with mail.connect() as conn:
    for contact in contacts:
        message = "Hi %s \n\n" % (contact['name']).capitalize()
        message += body
        subject = subject
        msg = Message(recipients=(contact['email']).split(),
                      sender=sender,
                      html=message,
                      subject=subject,
                      )
        for f in request.files.getlist('attachment'):
            msg.attach(filename=f.filename,
                       content_type=f.content_type,
                       data=f.read())
        conn.send(msg)
        f.seek(0)
    return Response("Success")
```

The only change in the code is the addition of the following statement.

```
f.seek(0)
```